# Async and sync javascript code in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();


function addAsync(a, b, callback) {
  callback( a + b );
}

function addSync(a, b) {

  return a + b;
}

app.use('/main', router);

router.use(function(req, res, next) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {

    addAsync(1, 2, function(a, b) {

    });

    //addSync();
  }

  next();

});

app.listen(3001);
```

I have 2 functions "addSync" and "addAsync".
I am using apache benchmark from console like this:
ab -n 1000 -c 1000 http://localhost:3001/main
where:
-c concurrency
Number of multiple requests to perform at a time. Default is one request at a time.
-n requests
Number of requests to perform for the benchmarking session. The default is to just perform a single request which usually leads to non-representative benchmarking results.

addSync executes in 0.613 seconds;
addAsync executes in 2.885 seconds

Why does asynchronous code take longer time to execute? Maybe it is because of the closure witch callback is creating.

If anyone knows where I can read about this stuff, I highly appreciate. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your `addAsync` function is not asynchronous; it's synchronous with an extra function call.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually I am just trying to compare  async and sync functions performance.

Comment: But you don't have anything that is asynchronous ?

Comment: The extra overhead happen because of the function call. Also `addAsync` is not a asynchronous function in the given example. I think the expense is due to the creation of nested stack for the callback function. This problem would be solved by [Tail Call optimization](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/tail-calls-optimization-es6/) coming in es6 for your code.

Comment: defining the callback function outside of the loop should improve perf.

Comment: Probably. Then what would be good to achieve and understand the difference between writing asynchronous and synchronous code and performance between them.

Comment: Again I'd like to point out that there's nothing here that's asynchronous. Asynchronous code solves a different problem to return vs callback. What you're testing here is really two things: cost of anonymous functions (you can create that callback as a named function) and callback function call overhead. But that says nothing about asynchronous code. Asynchronous code lets your code do other things while waiting for something that happens outside of your process (sometimes even outside of your PC) such as a database request to complete.

Comment: dandavis, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in your code is testing async functions. To test async functions you need to use async code. And async is not the result of syntax: the function implementation itself needs to either call C codec async code (such as `setTimeout()`) or itself be written in C.

Here's a better test:

```
var request = require('sync-request');
var http = require('http');

// sync test: get example.com 10 times:
console.log('starting sync test');

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var res = request('GET', 'http://www.example.com');
    console.log(res.getBody().length + ' bytes');
}
console.log('done sync test');

// async test
console.log('starting async test');
var processing = 10;

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    http.get("http://www.example.com", function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            processing--;
            console.log(body.length + ' bytes');

            if (processing == 0) {
                console.log('done async test');
            }
        });
    });
}
console.log('async requests all queued..');
```

Note that you need to install `sync-request`. Just do `npm install sync-request`.

While each function call of the async code is technically slower than the sync version, the async code finishes quicker because it's making 10 parallel requests instead of doing it one at a time. Therein lies the power of async code: it allows you to run other code while waiting for I/O thus you're not wasting CPU time.

Comment: Note: Technically node.js can't run code in parallel. The async requests are all sent and process in series one after the other. The parallelism is achieved because the processing that generates the response page happens on the `example.com` server.

Comment: Thanks. That also means I cannot model async code using only javascript.

Comment: If by model you mean model without using any built-in async functions then no. But you can use `setTimeout()` to effectively emulate asynchronous delays. Not sure what you can do to emulate a compatible synchronous delay

Comment: Also note that `example.com` is a real website set up by IETF to explain that `"example.com"` is a reserved domain name according to internet standards. So you can run the script above as-is